# Activate function with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried to active the function`dataBridge` with a button in Python use Tkinter, but when I press the buttons but nothing happens and dont runs the function.The idea is when press the button to ON the function is active,but when press the button OFF the function deactivate.The function `dataBridge`is to send a request and capture the data in real time.

```
from datetime import datetime
import serial
from xbee import XBee, ZigBee
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import sys
import Tkinter
PORT = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
BAUD_RATE = 38400
# Apertura del puerto serial
ser = serial.Serial(PORT, BAUD_RATE, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=None, xonxoff=1, rtscts=1, dsrdtr=1)

# Creacion de objeto API para lectura del puerto serial
xbee = XBee(ser)
#xbee = XBee(ser,escaped=True)
#Etiquetas de direccion para cada Xbee
Addr_sensor1= "\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\x69\x18\xF5"
Addr_sensor2= "\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\x69\x18\xF8"
Addr_sensor3= "\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\x69\x16\x64"

a=bool
top = Tkinter.Tk()
top.title("Red ")
top.geometry('500x250')

def dataBridge( ):
      while True:
         try:

                        xbee.tx_long_addr(frame= '0x81',dest_addr=Addr_sensor1,data='A')
                        response = xbee.wait_read_frame()
                        receive= response['rf_data']
                        my_set= receive.split(",")
                        if my_set[0]=="nodo_3":
                            ele=0
                            f= open("sensor_3.txt.","a")
                            for ele in my_set:
                                f.write('%s,' % ele)
                        elif my_set[0]=="nodo_1":
                            el=0
                            f= open("sensor_1.txt.","a")
                            for el in my_set:
                                f.write('%s,' % el)
                        elif my_set[0]=="nodo_2":
                            e=0
                            f= open("sensor_2.txt.","a")
                            for e in my_set:
                                f.write('%s,' % e)  
                        print my_set
                        time.sleep(0.03)

         except:
            break


def apertura():
   dataBridge()
   tkMessageBox.showinfo( "ON", "Sistema iniciado")



def cierre():
   tkMessageBox.showinfo( "OFF", "Sistema apagado")
   while True:
      try:
         break

      except:
         break


R = Text(top, height=20, width=55)
T = Label(top, text="Proyecto ")
T.pack()
R.insert(INSERT, "Oprima el boton de Activar para encender el sistema\nde lo contrario oprima Apagar\n")
R.pack()
B = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="Activar", command = apertura)
C = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="Apagar", command = cierre)
B.pack()
B.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=100, width=50,x=150,y=100)
C.pack()
C.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=100, width=50,x=300,y=100)
```

Comment: What evidence do you have that the function isn't running? Have you tried adding debug `print` statements to see if in fact the function is being called or not, or if you ever exit the infinite loop?

Comment: I tried to implement of many forms, for example use a `bool` to call when the button is ON the `bool ` is True ,but I print the bool and when press the button the value dont change.The other problem is that the loop, I didn't stop, the only form is stop in the terminal with kill the process.